# Rotate Eagle CAD component about its origin

Tags: pcb, design, eaglecad

Could someone help me redefine the center of rotation for a component please?
When I open the component in Eagle library I can see there is a little cross on one of the pins and at the moment when I rotate it turns about this point. I would like the cross in the middle of the part (it is a PCB-mounted potentiometer so between the 2 outer ground pins) so I can rotate about the center of the actual part.

Does anyone know how to move the little white cross to the center so I can turn the part around this point instead please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Library, and select the device you want to change. Open the device, and move everything, so that the Origin cross is centered in the middle of your component. Save and done. If you have used the component in your schematic/PCB, you will need to run "Update library".
Open the Library, and select the footprint you want to change. Open the footprint, and move everything, so that the Origin cross is centered in the middle pin of your footprint. Save and done. If you have used the component in your schematic/PCB, you will need to run "Update library".
*Edit: added both possible explanations*

Comment: I read the question to hastily, my bad. I thought OP was talking about the footprint.

Comment: I retract my comment, I'm not sure if the OP means the "actual part" as in the part on the PCB, or the "part" as in the device on the schematic.

Comment: Now you really got me questioning my sanity.

Comment: Hello thank you for your kind reply. I have moved the component to fit around the new origin! Thank you >)